# Interviewer pretending to have more candidates

Tags: interviewing

It happened more than once that I had the impression to be the only candidate but the interviewer talked about interviews (plural) or explicitly mentioned other candidates.

Don’t ask me how I got that feeling (every time was different) but I am quite sure I was right (for example, due to how quickly I was hired).

Do really interviewers do this? And if so, why?

Comment: Why does it matter?

Comment: @bayer - joeqwerty question is interesting and an answer from you would be helpful to answer the question fully

Comment: This sounds very ordinary. It would be relevant to the question of salary, of course. // Just to add another possible interpretation, it might mean that the hiring group had an explicit plan to have X number of finalists, even if they didn't have them yet at the time they interviewed you. If they make you an offer quickly in spite of that messaging, great news for you, you are doing well!

Comment: When you are being interviewed, you always have multiple options to choose from as well, don't you? :)

Comment: @Theo Tiger, almost always

Answer (score 12):

In a negotiation, you never want to invoke the impression that you don't have other options.

Interviewers will do that, interviewees will do it, too. Everybody else negotiating for something does it.

Comment: Thank you @nvoigt. That was one of my hypotheses together with testing how you perform under pressure.

Answer (score 5):

Not to be harsh but they really probably *do* have other candidates. It's a fallacy to go into an interview thinking "I'm the only choice". They may say that they have other candidates (in one form or another) for a few reasons:

1. Do not expect an immediate offer
2. Do not expect to be the only person hired for the position
3. Do still put your best foot forward
4. Do still show how you are the best *fit* compared to other choices
5. If you do not get picked, it is not because of an EEO (Equal Employment Opportunity) violation/etc.

Often it is to show that there is a fair process and that there are several options available so that they do not violate EEO (Equal Employment Opportunity) or have a candidate *think* they have the position locked.

Remember, you do not have the facts or all of the facts so you are making decisions and opinions based off of your perception and perspective of a fraction of the facts. Avoid being over confident or arrogant. Pride cometh before the fall.

Best of luck! :)

Comment: If the OP is hired quickly and they just attribute it to being the only candidate, then I think they could do with *more* pride, not less :-)

Comment: @mattfreake Generally, getting an immediate offer (at the end of an interview or the next day) is a red flag. It indicates problems and a lack of care for quality/thoroughness with making sure good decisions are being made.

Comment: What is EEO? Don't assume your readers know all abbreviations, especially if those abbreviations are country specific.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel That's a fair point. Most people would Google it but I edited the answer to include it.

Answer (score 2):

There are several reasons why it's common practice to say something like "we're still running interviews" or "we have a number of other candidates we're talking to".

The main one is simply to set the expectation that you might not get an answer immediately. While I will always try to let a candidate know if they're successful (or more importantly, unsuccessful) as soon as possible, that may not always be right away. Do I want to tell the candidate that I may not be able to make them an offer immediately because it depends on my disorganised and indecisive CEO to sign off on the hire? No. I'll just say, "I'll get back to you as soon as I can, but we've still got some other interviews to complete so it might not be right away".

The other reasons involve setting up the yes/no decision that will come later:

It primes the candidate to be ready to accept the decision, when it comes, whatever the decision ends up being. If they believe they are the only candidate, and get told "no", they are much more likely to argue about it (I've had people do this before, as if they can annoy me into making them a job offer); or, potentially, they might decide it must be because of prejudice, and decide to sue the company.

It also sets up being able to give them an answer in a way that may avoid hurting their feelings. "You were the only candidate, but we didn't think you were good enough" is hard to hear. "We had other candidates, and they seemed a better fit so we won't be considering your application further" is much less hurtful. So really, even if it's technically untrue, it's a social convention to smooth over the social interaction - just like saying "it was a pleasure to meet you", even if it wasn't!

Finally, and less positively, it may be used as a way to pressure the candidate into accepting, perhaps at a lower salary. This isn't something I would ever do, I would rather attract people to work for me by treating them well and paying them properly; but unscrupulous bosses might want to set up the opportunity to say or imply: "if you don't accept by Friday, we'll offer the job to someone else, and by the way they're asking for $5K/year less than you are...". How common this is may depend on industry and will certainly depend on the integrity of the hiring manager, but it will happen sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

#### Because it's terrible for negotiations.

> "Oh, you saw our ad on LocalCars and wanted to take a look at the red
> '16 Flooster?  Great car - I'm really surprised nobody else has even
> asked about it over the last 2 weeks."

... sounds like that car salesman sucks, right?  They simultaneously:

- Informed you that the demand for the car is extremely low and that the salesman will probably take any reasonable offer.
- Made you wonder if there's something wrong with it - after all, why would you be the only one wanting to take a look at it otherwise?

Well, it's the same thing with interviews:

> "Oh, you saw our job posting on LocalJobs and wanted to apply for the
> .NET dev position?  It's a great gig - I'm surprised you're the only
> person applying."

... same thing.  It just tells the applicant "Go ahead and be more aggressive in negotiating your salary with us - we'd likely be willing to bump it up by several thousand because our recruitment search hasn't been going well - and while you're at it, make sure you're extra diligent about background researching our company and carefully consider if there's some sort of red flag about us."

And that's just the negotiating facet.  There are all sorts of logistical reasons, too (which the other answers have done a great job of highlighting.)